# Load Application Services Created under library in AbpModule

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-boilerplate

I am using the Asp.Net Boilerplate framework. I have created one plain Asp.Net core library called `Test.ApplicationService`. I have added one Application Service in it called `TestAppService`.

I have also created one more AbpModule project called `Test.ApplicationService.Services`. It has reference to the `Test.ApplicationService` project. I have added ApplicationModule in this library as shown below-

```
[DependsOn(
typeof(AutoMapperModule))]
public class TestApplicationServiceModule : AbpModule
{
    public override void PreInitialize()
    {
        //Adding custom AutoMapper configuration
        Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().Configurators.Add(tESTCustomDtoMapper.CreateMappings);
    }
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(TestApplicationServiceModule).GetAssembly());
    }
}
```

I want to load my `TestAppService` which is defined in some other plain class library while loading my `TestApplicationServiceModule`. Is it possible to load the Application Service which is defined under plain library in ASP.Net Boiler Plate framework?

Comment: Isn't `TestApplicationServiceModule` the module for `Test.ApplicationService` project, which contains `TestAppService`? Please use clearer names.

Comment: If I understood you description correctly you want to register your  TestAppService in IOC. If this is correct then you can add the following line in `Initialize()` method you listed above `IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(TestAppService).GetAssembly())`

Comment: @saajshek Any update?